# Can "why" functionality questions be asked?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question based upon observations I've noticed  while working in Active Directory. Can I ask a "why" question in Superuser about functionality that I've observed or is Superuser strictly a "Break/Fix" site?

Comment: This was basically asked today. We'd probably recommend asking about actual problems, but it's not a strict rule that such questions will be closed. Asking for  technical details and reasons for implementing something one way instead of another could work.

Comment: Good point, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the head up!